# How to delete file .bat with pascal

Tags: batch-file, pascal

How can I delete files using pascal? (Not only .txt files)    Example:   I have a .bat file that have the directory  C:\Settings\BATCH.bat . How can I delete it?

```
Delete('C:\Settings\BATCH.bat');
```

Or something like that? What do I have to do?

Comment: What's wrong with `DeleteFile`?

Comment: Pascal is a language. File system support is not part of the standard. Please specify your development system

Comment: DeleteFile problem is that pascal haven't this command !

Comment: And marco, what do I have to specificate ?  The problem is: I want found a command in pascal that can delete a file in my computer. That can delete all file tipes, like .txt .bat .exe ecc...

Comment: When someone asks you for more information, it's because it's needed. `DeleteFile` is in the SysUtils unit for Delphi and FreePascal. You need to be specific because if you're using a different Pascal, or working on an OS other than Windows, it matters. And because this site requires **specific questions**, and the details you were asked for matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the *Erase* command:

```
Program deletefile;

{ Program to demonstrate the Erase function. }

Var F : Text;

begin
  { Create a file with a line of text in it}
  Assign (F,'test.txt');
  Rewrite (F);
  Writeln (F,'Try and find this when I''m finished !');
  close (f);
  { Now remove the file }
  Erase (f);
end.
```

You have to assign the file but don't open it (with Reset or Rewrite).
For more information visit the following doc page: http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/erase.html

Comment: Or sysutils.deletefile: http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/deletefile.html

Comment: But this isn't the best solution because you must load the SysUtils library and increase the RAM that the program needs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but, technically speaking, `SysUtils` is not a library, it's a unit. The compiler will take only relevant parts from it and add them into your program during compilation. If `DeleteFile` is the only `SysUtils` routine your program needs, using it won't make your program require an awful lot (if at all) larger amount of memory than using the `Assign`/`Erase` method. Don't mean to say `DeleteFile` would be better, especially since we know little about the OP's Pascal environment, just setting the record straight with regard to using units.